# I got PermissionError at admin login

Tags: python, django

I am new at django. I try to create superuser in django. I did all steps and they show me in terminal as I created superuser successfully. But when I go to server it shows permission error.

I reinstalled django without cache. But still same problem coming. First they show template not found, then I created one file `logging.html`. But again they show permission error.

```
# this code from admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Destinations

admin.site.register(Destinations)
```

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\abc\projects\amar\templates\admin\login.html'

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue. It was a permission error on directory and files

I use :

```
Chmod -R 775 templates/
```

All came back as Normal.